# How can I solve this MDX Problem?

Tags: ssas, mdx

I  want  to be comparing the previous and  current values, but my MDX query is giving the following error

```
"The CURRENTMEMBER function expects a hierarchy expression for the 1 argument."
```

How can I solve this problem?

My MDX query is below. please help

```
with member [Measures].[Growth] as ([Date].[Calendar].[Month].CurrentMember,[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount])-([Date].[Calendar].[Month].CurrentMember.PrevMember,[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount])
select
{[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount],[Measures].[Growth] }
on columns,
{([Date].[Calendar].[Month].Members)}
on rows
FROM [Adventure Works]
```

Answer (score 4):

Change your member statement to the following:

```
with member [Measures].[Growth] as ([Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember,[Measures].[Internet   Sales Amount])-([Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember.PrevMember,[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount])
```

The currentmember function works off of a hiearchy.

Comment: If you also have the [Month] as its own attribute hierarchy, you could use [Date].[Month].CurrentMember instead.